# Why won't ">> " print at the end of my printf statement?

Tags: java, input, cmd, textcolor, text-coloring

I am trying to use the Jansi Java Library for using color in the CMD/Console and I have come across a little problem. When I use the Jansi Library and try to use the print f statement

```
System.out.printf("Hello young lad! What is thy " + RED + "name " + WHITE + "you were given at birth?\n>> ");
```

the ">> " doesn't print at the end. Instead, the Scanner is called and asks for my input. Why does this happen and is there any way i can make it so that the ">> " and the Scanner input appear on one line?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnsiConsole.systemInstall();

        String name;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String BLACK = "\u001B[0;30m";
        String RED = "\u001B[0;31m";
        String GREEN = "\u001B[0;32m";
        String YELLOW = "\u001B[0;33m";
        String BLUE = "\u001B[0;34m";
        String MAGENTA = "\u001B[0;35m";
        String CYAN = "\u001B[0;36m";
        String WHITE = "\u001B[0;37m";

        System.out.printf("Hello young lad! What is thy " + RED + "name " + WHITE + "you were given at birth?\n>> ");
        name = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `System.out.flush();` before your call to `nextLine()`.

Comment: Ignoring the AnsiConsole stuff, it works for me. Looks like your system might be line buffered to me.

Comment: You are calling `printf`, but aren't using any of its features. Better use `print` if you don't know that `printf` is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine after commenting out the AnsiConsole thing.

This is what I get printed out.

```
Hello young lad! What is thy [0;31mname [0;37myou were given at birth?
>> John
```

Comment: What if the issue is related to the Jansi's console ?

Comment: @zakinster Then it would be related to the jAnsi's ANSI console.